# How to reduce size of image while user upload in Yii2 framework

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have a website built on Yii framework, I am facing the issue that the images uploaded on the website by users are making the website slow hence my bounce rate is getting very high.

I tried to place a check for users to upload the images below 100KB

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up validation. https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/tutorial-core-validators#file